# Generating site map using PHP and MySQL by current_timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, sql, timestamp

I have MySQL database records:
post_id int, post_title text, post_date timestamp (with default value current_timestamp)

How can I generate site map using PHP with following structure without empty date nodes in result (where posts are from database only), e.g.:

```
2010
- 2010 Jan
-- 2010 Jan 10
--- post-1
--- post-2
-- 2010 Jan 12
--- post-3
-- 2010 Jan 17
--- post-4
- 2010 Feb
-- 2010 Frb 05
--- post-5
2011
- 2011 Dec
-- 2011 Dec 02
--- post-6
--- post-7
-- 2011 Dec 21
--- post-8
```

etc.

Comment: The best way is: 1) main page with links 2010, 2011; 2) second (child page 2010) with links 2010 Jan, 2010 Feb etc. Hierarchy pages by date nodes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sitemap script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123800/sitemap-script)

Comment: I don't know how to make an optimal query. Firstly to select all records that match 2010 and then select from them all that match 2010 Jan. But it's too many requests. I need iterate all days in each year. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to select your data so that it's convenient to print it out in your structure. Should be something like this:

```
SELECT day(post_date) as day, month(post_date) as month, year(post_date) as year,
DATE_FORMAT(post_date,"%Y-%m-%d") as created_at, post_title,
post_id FROM posts ORDER BY created_at;
```

Then you iterate through the result and build a multi dimensional index with year, month and day as index. One entry could look like this:

```
$data[2013][10][31] = array("post1", "post2");
```

Having that it's easy to print out your sitemap (just a couple of foreach constructions).

Comment: sorry, first version was buggy (you have to group by the whole date, if you want to cover more than one year).

Comment: You mean ORDER BY, not GROUP BY.

Comment: you are totally right. faulty comment, but at least the ORDER BY is still in the query ;-)